# Convert ruby on rails models to MongoDB collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, model

I have some code for a ruby on rails website, but I dont have the MongoDB or the schema for the website. But I do have the models for each of the mongodb collections.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a schema or build the new collections in the database automatically from the models.

Here's an example of one of my models:

```
class ForumPost
include Mongoid::Document

field :date, type: Time
field :edited, type: Boolean, default: false
field :content, type: String
field :quote, type: BSON::ObjectId

belongs_to :forum_topic
belongs_to :user

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all of the model/schema information that you need.  Simply create Mongoid model objects and persist them to MongoDB, filling in the appropriate fields and supplying data for associated models as desired.  Unlike RDBMS, there's no need for setting up formal schema definition on the DB side.